# How can I output #define value

Tags: c++, c

I am new to this forum so please go easy on me :)

I have the following in my code

```
#define SYS_SBS     0x02
```

Whenever I try to use this and try to output,I get 2 as the value, however I want to get SYS_SBS as the output for my program. Is there a way, I can do this.

I have no control over the source code. I just have to output SYS_SBS.

Additional Details: I cannot change some the header files. However I can change the main function in .cpp file. I want the SYS_SBS as the output. I am working with satellites and for all the satellited detected by my receiver, I have to output what type of sattelite they are. In the code all of them are defined with this hexadecimal number. I just want to output SYS_SBS and not 2

Comment: I don't think you can, because the preprocessor replace all the SYS_SBS by the value

Comment: If you want `SYS_SBS` as output, just output `SYS_SBS`

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: 0x02 is 2. What did you expect, or do you want the string SYS_SBS?

Comment: I do not think you can print preprocessor directly.

Comment: Do you mean the string `"SYS_SBS"`? Because the value of `SYS_SBS` *is* 2.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I cannot change the source code. I want the SYS_SBS as the output. I am working with satellites and for all the satellited detected by my receiver, I have to output what type of sattelite they are. In the code all of them are defined with this hexadecimal number. I just want to output SYS_SBS and not 2.

Comment: If you cannot change the source code, how can you output anything then? Do you want a lookup table from 0x02 --> SYS_SBS ?

Comment: Since you have no control over the source code, how do you even expect to do this..

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I cannot change some the header files. However I can change the main function in .cpp file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SYS_SBS     0x02 
#define id(x) #x

int main(){
    printf("%s %d\n", id(SYS_SBS), SYS_SBS);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He said he has no control over the source code. How could he edit the source code?

Comment: This is essentially the same as just printing "SYS_SBS" directly. In particular, it does not perform any kind of sanity check. If you have a typo in the parameter to your `id()` macro you will only notice once it's too late. The question is a bit weird, but this answer is really not much better.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question well maybe.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard provides a [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) operator (add a # in front of the token) that allows you to outuput a specific token.

What's not possible is to convert backwards from a variable's value to this token name as this is lost during translations (as others have mentioned). If you need that kind of conversion, think about a explicit "value2str" function that returns a string representation of a given value:

```
const char *myType2str(int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case SYS_SBS:
            return "SYS_SBS";

        default:
            return "UNKNOWN VALUE";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: According to some comments, stringification is part of the standard. Changed that. Thanks for the hint. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: some? stringification is part of the standard.

Comment: Not some, all C and C++ compilers provide this.

Comment: @refp thanks for the hint. Wasn't aware that this is a standard feature.

Comment: @LBg Actually I prefer the single return statement variant over the one you just patched in my answer. But you were right: I forgot the return statement in my example.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`0x02` is the hexadecimal representation in the *source*. Once you compiled it, it's just a number (2).</strike>

If you want to print it as hex, then, well... print it as hex (eg: use the formatting string `"0x%.2x"`).

Well, you could simply:

```
printf("SYS_SBS");
```

But I assume you have a number as "input" (like 2), and want to output the string `SYS_SBS`, well, that's not directly possible. The best you can do is create a lookup table, eg:

```
const char* sys_strings[] = { "SYS_EX", "SYS_TEM", "SYS_SBS" };
```